# Save text field in javascript in kendo ui jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

In order to save a field as a string, I have written the following code, but the problem is that it encounters an error.

e.model.set('productionPlanningYear', productionPlanningYear.toJSON());

This is the error message :  toJSON is not a function

```
                        save: function (e) {
                        var productionPlanningYear = $('#productionPlanningYear').data('kendoMaskedTextBox').value();
                        if (!productionPlanningYear) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            kmc.alert(kendo.format(planning.res.RequiredMsg, planning.res.ProductionPlanningYear));
                        } else {
                            e.model.set('productionPlanningYear', productionPlanningYear.toJSON());
                            var details = $('#planning-details-grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
                            $.each(details, function (i, v) {
                                if (v.id < 0) {
                                    v.set('id', 0);
                                }
                            });
                            e.model.set('details', details.toJSON());
                        }
                    }
                }).data('kendoGrid');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value()` method of `kendoMaskedTextBox` returns a string.

The `toJSON()` method exists on Date objects.

You can convert the string you get from the `kendoMaskedTextBox` using `new Date(kendoMaskedTextBox)` and then call `value()`, like this:

```
const value = $('#productionPlanningYear').data('kendoMaskedTextBox').value();
const productionPlanningYear = new Date(value);
console.log(productionPlanningYear.toJSON);
```